# Visual Studio asking for poetry generated virtual environment every time

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I have switched to managing my virtual environments with poetry and chose to configure it so that it installs each virtual environment in the root of each project.

I usually go to my project folder and issue a `poetry shell` command,

The virtual environment used is shown by the `poetry env info -p` which as an example returns:

```
/Users/bob/Documents/work/code/isagog-ai/.venv
```

From this shell I run `code .` and Visual Studio correctly starts but every time it warns me of [image]
and the blue button brings me to my virtual environments such as:
[image] to which every time I just need to select the recommended ./.venv environment. All is fine thereafter.

Why doesn't this choice "stick" for this project like it did for conda managed environments?

Comment: Is this solvable by setting `"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python"` in your [workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings)?

Comment: This sounded so interesting and got my hopes high, but alas no, same behaviour :( Thanks a lot.